# Apache POI Zip File is closed

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi, doc

I'm creating a web API (with Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE) that take in the input a dotx file and params (like name or phone) , in the output it create docx file with changes(I'm using Apache POI 4.0.1).

steps:

1- take the input dotx and params.

2- convert dotx to docx.

3- add params to docx file and send it.

the Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/addcontent")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> convertion(@RequestParam(value = "file",required = false) MultipartFile file,@RequestParam(value="input",required = false) String para) throws  InvalidFormatException, IOException{
    Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();
    m.put("namur",para);
    String document = "D:/"+file.getContentType().substring(0, file.getOriginalFilename().length() - 4)+"docx";
    ChangeDot.addContentTodot(m, file.getOriginalFilename(),document );

    FileSystemResource out = new FileSystemResource(document);

     return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentLength(out.contentLength())
                .contentType(
                        MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"))
                .body(new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(out.getInputStream())));
}
```

}

the ChangeDot class(this class do all the traitement) the controller just call it :

```
public class ChangeDot {

private ChangeDot() {
}

public  static void addContentTodot(Map<String, String> m , String dot , String document ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    //convert Dotx to Docx
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(dot)) ;
    doc.getPackage().replaceContentType(
               "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template.main+xml",
               "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml");

    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = m.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, String> pair = it.next();
         String key=(String) pair.getKey();
         String val =(String) pair.getValue();
         for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
             List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
             if (runs != null) {
                 for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                     String text = r.getText(0);
                     if (text != null ) {

                         text = text.replace(key, val);// your content
                         r.setText(text, 0);

                     }
                 }
             }
        }
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException

    }
    doc.write(new FileOutputStream(document));
    doc.close();

}
```

}

The problem is: when i try to send a request with PostMan I get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip File is closed
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipFileZipEntrySource.getEntries(ZipFileZipEntrySource.java:45) ~[poi-ooxml-3.13.jar:3.13]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:184) ~[poi-ooxml-3.13.jar:3.13]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:684) ~[poi-ooxml-3.13.jar:3.13]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:227) ~[poi-ooxml-3.13.jar:3.13]
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:187) ~[poi-ooxml-3.13.jar:3.13]
at sofadev.docapost.phenix.server.changedot.controller.ApiController.convertion(ApiController.java:56) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

Please, If there is any suggestion, do not hesitate.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're passing the `MultipartFile.getOriginalFilename()` value (which is the name of the file on the client system) to the `OPCPackage.open()` method, which expects the file name on the server.

You should do something like this instead (`file` is the `MultipartFile` instance):

```java
InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(inputStream));
```

Comment: Yes, Indeed the problem was in the input file !

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
@PostMapping("/addcontent")
public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> convertion(@RequestParam(value = "file",required = false) MultipartFile file,@RequestParam(value="input",required = false) String para) throws  InvalidFormatException, IOException{
    Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();
    m.put("namur",para);
    String document = "D:/"+file.getContentType().substring(0, file.getOriginalFilename().length() - 4)+"docx";
    ChangeDot.addContentTodot(m, file.getOriginalFilename(),document );

    FileSystemResource out = new FileSystemResource(document);

     return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentLength(out.contentLength())
                .contentType(
                        MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"))
                .body(out);
}
```